# If you have a branch with no upstream in a Git repo with more than one remote, how does Visual Studio choose which remote to use when you push?

Tags: visual-studio

If I have a Git repo open in Visual Studio and said repo has multiple remotes and I select "push" while a branch with no upstream is checked out, Visual Studio automatically sets the branch's upstream to "origin". Why does it choose the "origin" remote over the repo's other remotes?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtremote, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-branchltnamegtpushRemote, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remotepushDefault

Comment: @phd I think `branch.<name>.remote` and `branch.<name>.pushRemote` are only be set if a branch named <name> has a tracking set up.

Also, I checked the value of `remote.pushDefault`, but it doesn't appear to be set on my repo.

Comment: You'd have to ask the Visual Studio guys, not the Git guys; Git doesn't do this. Maybe drop the [tag:git] tag?

Comment: @torek Does including both `git` and `visual-studio` tags not direct the question at both parties?

Comment: Because StackOverflow treats the tags as an "or" (you get to see some question if it's tagged with any of your tags), people tend to answer a question with tag X with an X-specific answer. A tighter focus gets you fewer but more-relevant answers, in general.

Comment: @torek Okay, thanks. I've removed the `visual-studio` tag.